AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'
I tried to pursue my survey on otree but it always shows "Internal Server Error" when running the demo.
Python, otree etc are all updated on the latest version.
error message:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6299, in getattr
return object.getattribute(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_mgr'
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Downgrading to pandas==2.2.1 resolved this issue for me, although I ran into the same error in a different context (not related to oTree).
